# Angular $http.get() does not work in Phonegap DevApp

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

For my Phonegap App I'm trying to load a JSON file using angulars $http.

I got this service:

```
cApp.factory('language', function ($http) {
    return {
        getLanguageData: function () {
            return $http.get('../../lang/' + lang.substr(0,2) + '.json');
        }
    }
});
```

Which I use in this controller:

```
cApp.controller('initController', function ($scope, language) {   
    language.getLanguageData().success(function (data) {        
        $scope.language = data;
    }).catch(function (e) {
        alert("error" + e);
    });
});
```

This works fine in my browser, but not in Phonegap Developerapp on Android. The controller does not write the `language` variable, and does not alert anything (not even "error").

**What i tried:**

With a `.catch().then().catch()` chain it returned me data which was `null` in the last `.catch()`.

I tought about if it's a cross origin problem, but my phonegap whitelist allows all domains (`<access origin="*" />`).

The files should be in the same domain anyways, since my folder structure looks like this:

```
.myapp
├── www
|   ├── js
|   |   ├── controller
|   |   |   └── initController.js
|   |   └── service
|   |       └── language.js
|   └── lang
|       ├── en.json
|       └── de.json
└── config.xml
```

What am I doing wrong, missing?

**UPDATE: Partial solution found:**

It works if i execute the `get()` using the whole path:

```
return $http.get('file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/json/lang/' + lang.substr(0,2) + '.json');
```

That's not a proper solution since it won't work on iOS (different path). I don't get why I can't use `../../lang/`.

Comment: I think you probably have the wrong relative path. Maybe you are going too many levels up and the browser version hits the root folder and ignores the `..` but the phonegap app goes up too far. Probably you should be using `'/lang/'` as the path.

Comment: I tried it but it does not do the trick. My controller JS is in this folder on the app: ´file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/controller/´ so I think the path might be fine

Answer (score 0):

You should just handle it as file using the [file-api for cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html) apps.