# PhoneGap - Angularjs http service (PHP API call) Not Working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap, angularjs-http

I try to use **Angularjs http service** to call my PHP API. Everything working fine in Browser. But, when I test it on my Android Phone, it will not work.

**My Issue:**

In Android PhoneGap Application, Whenever I trigger the **Angularjs http service** it will always trigger the `function (error)` even when the Mobile is connected with Internet.

I have try look this but their solution aren't working:

1. [Angular $http.get() does not work in Phonegap DevApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634992/angular-http-get-does-not-work-in-phonegap-devapp)
2. [Cordova 5.3.1 Android app can't access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605034/cordova-5-3-1-android-app-cant-access-the-internet)

I also have ensure the Phonegap `config.xml` has allowed Internet Permission Access with:

```
<access allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media="true" allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content="true" allows-local-networking="true" origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

However it is still not Working.

**My Question:**

1. Is Angularjs http service is not able to work on PhoneGap Mobile Application but only Web Browser?
2. Aside from `config.xml` , is there any other configuration have to be made to allow PhoneGap Mobile Application to access the Internet?

**Angularjs code:**

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'email' : $scope.email,
        'password' : $scope.password,
    },
    url: 'https://unsurfaced-cross.000webhostapp.com/PGLogin.php'
 }).then(function (response){
    $scope.users = response.data;

    if(response.data[0]=="LOGIN"){
      alert("Successful Login");
      $window.location.href = './homepage.html';

    }else{
      alert("Login Failed. Incorrect Email or Password.");
    }

 },function (error){
      alert("Please ensure You are connected to Internet.");
 });
```

Comment: What does the error in the error callback say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem like actually I just didn't install the `whitelist` plugin, for my case the `whitelist` plugin didn't installed by Default.

Since I was using PhoneGap, instead of using command like `cordova-plugin-whitelist@latest`, `cordova create`, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` or etc.

I should use: `phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

After install the Whitelist Plugin, everything working fine.

So,

1. Angularjs http service is able to work on PhoneGap Mobile Application.
2. Aside from config.xml , we have to ensure that all necessary and required plugin was installed such as Whitelist plugin.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, also I added and removed the plugin for making sure